# SEO impact when using existing domain for a new website

Tags: seo

I want to use my existing domain for my new real estate website. My existing domain is more into entertainment content and wasn't much traffic and with 98% bounce rate. So is it recommended to use my existing domain for my new website or opt for a new domain. Please advise cons

Comment: Why not? That is your right to do. If your site is not performing well, then anything you do to make it perform better is a step up. Right? Search engines are not people. They are machines. In other words, they do not get mad or anything. They just do their job. Many sites switch gears over time. I have several times for my own site and may be again soon. Do not worry about it. Just know it will take a bit of time to reprocess your site again for search. Not a big deal. Just be patient and it will all work out. Best of luck!!

Comment: i'm in general with closetnoc, if you own this domain. if you plan to buy one, be aware of possible penalties or black seo techniques, applied to the domain you buy. research its in-depth history before buying.